# How to set a boolean value in an array object in a plist

Tags: macos, plist

I'm trying to modify my settings for Textmate by modifying its plist. Here's what I've got so far:

```
defaults write com.macromates.textmate OakShellVariables -array-add '{value = "hello"; variable = "TM_HELLO";}'
```

This will add in a new shell variable for Textmate. I'm wanting to do this via the command line so that I can script it. The above works fine but I also want to set the enabled key (which is a boolean) to true. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax to achieve this. All my attempts result in setting the enabled key to be a string instead of a boolean. For example:

```
defaults write com.macromates.textmate OakShellVariables -array-add '{enabled = true ;value = "hello"; variable = "TM_HELLO";}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how you do it Michael.  I was looking for the same thing, and I happened to come across the answer.  Thought I'd share.  Example shown below.

```
defaults write com.apple.dashboard layer-gadgets -array-add "<dict><key>32bit</key><false/></dict>";
```

These are the data types:

- `<string></string>` - string
- `<false/><true/>` - boolean
- `<real></real>` - real
- `<integer></integer>` - integer

Comment: It's better to use e.g. -string, -dict etc. instead of "<string></string>", as Apple will take care for the correct syntax. So you should be safe, also for future changes.